# Group Number By Using Permutation and Combination in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, grouping, combinations, permutation, vba

Suppose that we have **N** number or data and we want to put those number or data into a group that contains **k** number. For example: let **A** be a set of number {1, 2, 3} and I want to put them into groups that contains 2 number. If I use [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), I will get {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,3}, {3,1}, and {3,2}. If I use [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), I will get {1,2}, {1,3}, and {2,3}. I want each group is placed in different row and each number in different cells, for example: {1,2} in first row (**cells(1,1) = 1** and **cells(1,2) = 2**), and so on like the example below.

---

1 | 2

---

1 | 3

---

2 | 1

---

2 | 3

---

3 | 1

---

3 | 2

---

How to make a VBA Excel program to do thing such that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.  This small macro will list the permutations of **N** values taken two at a time:

```
Sub Permutations()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rr As Long
    N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter N", Type:=1)
    rr = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        For j = 1 To N
            Cells(rr, 1) = i
            Cells(rr, 2) = j
            rr = rr + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you need more than two items per group, modify the code to add loops as necessary.  If you need the groups to consist of items other than simple numbers, use the results of the macro to drive **VLOOKUP()** columns.

**NOTE:**

If you need to eliminate duplicates, then use this version:

```
Sub Permutations2()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rr As Long
    N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter N", Type:=1)
    rr = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        For j = 1 To N
            If i <> j Then
                Cells(rr, 1) = i
                Cells(rr, 2) = j
                rr = rr + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code Gary. But how if I have a set data {4,5,8,9,19} and I want to put them into groups where each group contains 3 or maybe 4 data? Your code only works for consecutive set numbers.